# Soap Sending Handled Manually - XmlNode: NodeTypes and Attributes read only

Tags: c#, soap, xmlnode

I have to make a call to a webservice but building the xml manually. I've chosen System.Xml to do this but it's causing me a lot of pain.

Every SOAP I know consts of 3 parts:

- The XmlDeclaration
- The Header of the    envelope or  SOAP-ENV:Envelope
- The
  Body of the envelope or
  SOAP-ENV:Body

The thing is my XmlDocument only can contain one root element. (Don't know why)
If I do

```
MyXMLDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.DocumentFragment, "SOAP-ENV", "Envelope", "http://tempuri.org");
```

It does not let me append attributes. It says those are read only.

RESUMING:

How do I have to do to write **this** but without the root and with an XmlDeclaration? and how do I call a webservice (with this xml)?

```
-<root>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" /> 
- <SOAP-ENV:Body>
- <ZbcInsertRequest xmlns:ns1="'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style'">
  <Destino>qas</Destino> 
- <IClrQst>
  <Request>foo</Request> 
  <Proyecto>foofoo</Proyecto> 
  <Modulocq /> 
  <Titureq>foofoofoo</Titureq> 
  <Tiporeq /> 
  <Prioridad>0</Prioridad> 
  <Clasific /> 
  <Asignadoa>foofoofoofoo</Asignadoa> 
  <Destino>qas</Destino> 
  <Solicita>foo</Solicita> 
  <Autoriza>c.foo</Autoriza> 
  <ModTransp /> 
  <ReqSox>F</ReqSox> 
  <Notfylst /> 
  <Tipodeploy>Normal</Tipodeploy> 
  <Paqdeploy>CDVQA00000000</Paqdeploy> 
  </IClrQst>
- <TRequest>
- <item>
  <Trkorr>DESK9A0ZJT</Trkorr> 
  <Secuencia>0</Secuencia> 
  <Solicita>c.foo</Solicita> 
  <Type /> 
  <Id /> 
  <Numero /> 
  <Message /> 
  </item>
  </TRequest>
  </ZbcInsertRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </root>
```

Here's the wsdl i'm connecting to

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:simpleType name="char1">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char10">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char100">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="100"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char15">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="15"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char20">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char220">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="220"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char255">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char30">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="30"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char32">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="32"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char50">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="numeric3">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
<xsd:pattern value="\d*"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="numeric6">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
<xsd:pattern value="\d*"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:import namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions"/>
<xsd:simpleType name="char1">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="1"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char10">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char12">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="12"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char120">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="120"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char20">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="20"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char250">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="250"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char3">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="3"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char4">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="4"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char60">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="60"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="date">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
<xsd:pattern value="\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="numeric5">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="5"/>
<xsd:pattern value="\d*"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="numeric6">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="6"/>
<xsd:pattern value="\d*"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="time">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="8"/>
<xsd:pattern value="\d\d:\d\d:\d\d"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="ZtyEE070">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Trkorr" type="tns:char20"/>
<xsd:element name="As4text" type="tns:char60"/>
<xsd:element name="Trfunction" type="n0:char1"/>
<xsd:element name="Trstatus" type="n0:char1"/>
<xsd:element name="Tarsystem" type="tns:char10"/>
<xsd:element name="Korrdev" type="tns:char4"/>
<xsd:element name="As4user" type="tns:char12"/>
<xsd:element name="As4date" type="tns:date"/>
<xsd:element name="As4time" type="tns:time"/>
<xsd:element name="Strkorr" type="tns:char20"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ZtyEE071">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Trkorr" type="n0:char20"/>
<xsd:element name="As4pos" type="tns:numeric6"/>
<xsd:element name="Pgmid" type="tns:char4"/>
<xsd:element name="Object" type="tns:char4"/>
<xsd:element name="Objname" type="tns:char120"/>
<xsd:element name="Objfunc" type="tns:char1"/>
<xsd:element name="Lockflag" type="tns:char1"/>
<xsd:element name="Gennum" type="tns:char3"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Zclrqstdat">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Request" type="n0:char15"/>
<xsd:element name="Proyecto" type="n0:char50"/>
<xsd:element name="Modulocq" type="tns:char250"/>
<xsd:element name="Titureq" type="tns:char250"/>
<xsd:element name="Tiporeq" type="n0:char30"/>
<xsd:element name="Prioridad" type="n0:char15"/>
<xsd:element name="Clasific" type="n0:char100"/>
<xsd:element name="Asignadoa" type="n0:char50"/>
<xsd:element name="Destino" type="n0:char10"/>
<xsd:element name="Solicita" type="n0:char50"/>
<xsd:element name="Autoriza" type="n0:char50"/>
<xsd:element name="Modtransp" type="n0:char1"/>
<xsd:element name="Reqsox" type="n0:char1"/>
<xsd:element name="Notfylst" type="n0:char255"/>
<xsd:element name="Tipodeploy" type="n0:char50"/>
<xsd:element name="Paqdeploy" type="n0:char15"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Zrequest">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Trkorr" type="n0:char20"/>
<xsd:element name="Secuencia" type="tns:numeric5"/>
<xsd:element name="Solicita" type="n0:char50"/>
<xsd:element name="Type" type="n0:char1"/>
<xsd:element name="Id" type="n0:char20"/>
<xsd:element name="Numero" type="n0:numeric3"/>
<xsd:element name="Message" type="n0:char220"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="Bapiret2">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Type" type="n0:char1"/>
<xsd:element name="Id" type="n0:char20"/>
<xsd:element name="Number" type="n0:numeric3"/>
<xsd:element name="Message" type="n0:char220"/>
<xsd:element name="Logno" type="n0:char20"/>
<xsd:element name="Logmsgno" type="n0:numeric6"/>
<xsd:element name="Messagev1" type="n0:char50"/>
<xsd:element name="Messagev2" type="n0:char50"/>
<xsd:element name="Messagev3" type="n0:char50"/>
<xsd:element name="Messagev4" type="n0:char50"/>
<xsd:element name="Parameter" type="n0:char32"/>
<xsd:element name="Row" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element name="Field" type="n0:char30"/>
<xsd:element name="System" type="n0:char10"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="TableOfztyEE070">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:ZtyEE070"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="TableOfztyEE071">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:ZtyEE071"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="TableOfzrequest">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:Zrequest"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="ZbcInsertRequest">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Destino" type="n0:char32"/>
<xsd:element name="EtRequestHeader" minOccurs="0" type="tns:TableOfztyEE070"/>
<xsd:element name="EtRequestObj" minOccurs="0" type="tns:TableOfztyEE071"/>
<xsd:element name="IClrqst" type="tns:Zclrqstdat"/>
<xsd:element name="TRequest" type="tns:TableOfzrequest"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ZbcInsertRequestResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="EtRequestHeader" minOccurs="0" type="tns:TableOfztyEE070"/>
<xsd:element name="EtRequestObj" minOccurs="0" type="tns:TableOfztyEE071"/>
<xsd:element name="Return" type="tns:Bapiret2"/>
<xsd:element name="TRequest" type="tns:TableOfzrequest"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ZbcInsertRequestString">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="EtRequestHeader" minOccurs="0" type="tns:TableOfztyEE070"/>
<xsd:element name="EtRequestObj" minOccurs="0" type="tns:TableOfztyEE071"/>
<xsd:element name="Sdestino" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="SiClrqst" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="TRequest" type="tns:TableOfzrequest"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ZbcInsertRequestStringResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="EtRequestHeader" type="tns:TableOfztyEE070"/>
<xsd:element name="EtRequestObj" type="tns:TableOfztyEE071"/>
<xsd:element name="Return" type="tns:Bapiret2"/>
<xsd:element name="TRequest" type="tns:TableOfzrequest"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<style/>
<wsdl:message name="ZbcInsertRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZbcInsertRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ZbcInsertRequestResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZbcInsertRequestResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ZbcInsertRequestString">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZbcInsertRequestString"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ZbcInsertRequestStringResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ZbcInsertRequestStringResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<sap:Feature name="design_0 " uri="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/authentication/">
<sap:Property qname="n1:AuthenticationLevel">
<sap:Option value="n1:None"/>
</sap:Property>
</sap:Feature>
<wsdl:portType name="ZICQ">
<sap:useFeature feature="tns:design_0 "/>
<wsdl:operation name="ZbcInsertRequest">
<wsdl:input message="tns:ZbcInsertRequest"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:ZbcInsertRequestResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="ZbcInsertRequestString">
<wsdl:input message="tns:ZbcInsertRequestString"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:ZbcInsertRequestStringResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="ZICQSoapBinding" type="tns:ZICQ">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="ZbcInsertRequest">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="ZbcInsertRequestString">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="ZICQService">
<wsdl:port name="ZICQSoapBinding" binding="tns:ZICQSoapBinding">
<soap:address location="http://hmxwasd1.hylsamex.com.mx:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/ZICQ?sap-client=100"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific question: in a SOAP envelope the Body element needs to be a child of the Envelope. You can't have the envelope be an empty element and the body following it. The code below shows how to load a modified version of this document in a XmlDocument object.

```
    public class StackOverflow_6157636_751090
    {
        public static void Test()
        {
            string xml = @"  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""> 
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <ZbcInsertRequest xmlns:ns1=""urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"">
  <Destino>qas</Destino> 
 <IClrQst>
  <Request>foo</Request> 
  <Proyecto>foofoo</Proyecto> 
  <Modulocq /> 
  <Titureq>foofoofoo</Titureq> 
  <Tiporeq /> 
  <Prioridad>0</Prioridad> 
  <Clasific /> 
  <Asignadoa>foofoofoofoo</Asignadoa> 
  <Destino>qas</Destino> 
  <Solicita>foo</Solicita> 
  <Autoriza>c.foo</Autoriza> 
  <ModTransp /> 
  <ReqSox>F</ReqSox> 
  <Notfylst /> 
  <Tipodeploy>Normal</Tipodeploy> 
  <Paqdeploy>CDVQA00000000</Paqdeploy> 
  </IClrQst>
 <TRequest>
 <item>
  <Trkorr>DESK9A0ZJT</Trkorr> 
  <Secuencia>0</Secuencia> 
  <Solicita>c.foo</Solicita> 
  <Type /> 
  <Id /> 
  <Numero /> 
  <Message /> 
  </item>
  </TRequest>
  </ZbcInsertRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(ms, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = false, Encoding = encoding, IndentChars = "  " });
            doc.Save(w);
            w.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
        }
    }
```

Now, another option you can consider (if possible) is not to send the SOAP request "manually", but use some tool (such as WCF or some other SOAP library) to create a proxy which you can use to send requests to the service. That way your client can simply "call a method" and the stack will take care of creating the SOAP envelope for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that I've tried but the reference.cs does not compile, and Even when I change the references to compile The return gives me a Deserialization Fault (a tipical unclearifying sap error from the websvc I'm calling). Besides, isn't there a way to do this handling the xml structure with xmlnode and/or xmlelement? because Im not sure if creating a large string is the best since I have to concat the values of each xml-tag. And another thing: Where and how do you handle the response this throws?

Comment: If the reference doesn't compile, then it's a bug on the Add Web/Service Reference - if you can post the WSDL which was used to generate it I can bring to the WCF team.

Comment: @carlosfigueira, Actually the WSDL works the way you posted at first... And it does work. But it's horrible to refactor, or to fix.

Comment: I mean, this was that way **before**. (I'm not creating a new connection to the Webservice), I'm only refactoring it. This was made in vbscript with asp3.0, but we are now working with .net and this had to be migrated to the current technology. I can't change the web-method because there is some privilege stuff and bureaucracy involved. Any ideas?

Comment: Ill put this as a correct answer because it is, but my problem remains.

Comment: Can you expand on why you need to expand / fix the reference created for the service? You say you can't change the web method, so the service part is fixed; the client side generated by ASR should contain all the information that the service needs for processing the request. Or are you trying to pass an additional infromation on the request?

Comment: It was made in vbscript embedded in an IBMClearQuest Hook (an old version) of the product. The code executed must follow another flow (Where the webscv call has to be done afterwards and outside ClearQuest).